# IE goes behind when open jQuery UI dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have a very strange problem when using `jQuery UI dialog`, everytime when I open a dialog using `IE`, the browser will go to behind. BTW, I have no problem using Firefox, Chrome & Safari.

**EDIT**

the cause of the problem is I added `$('*').blur();` after the dialog open, the purpose is to remove the `auto focus`.

Comment: Is it happening when trying jQuery UI dialog on jQuery demo page?

Comment: Are you trying to open the dialog from a plain html page or from another floating div, dialog or tab?

Comment: What version of IE is this happening on, and you elaborate on what you mean by "go to behind"?

Comment: @EtienneDesgagné no, from a html page

Comment: @TiesonT. so far, ie8 & ie9 for sure.

Comment: $('').bind('dialogopen', function () {
        // UI enhancement - remove auto focus when dialog open
        $('*').blur();
    }); this is the cause